# Updating a clip-path in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mousemove, clip

In my recent project, I am interested in creating a clip-path which moves with my mousemove. My initial idea was simply to select and re-position the ellipsis with its attributes `cx` and `cy` using the mousemove coordinates, then selecting the rectangle and re-initializing its `clip-path` attribute.

This, however, does not seem to work. The only workable solution I have found so far is to delete the rectangle and the clip-path, then re-initializing them at the new coordinates. This works fine for the simple test-case below, but in my actual experiment, the object I'll try to clip is an externally loaded svg, and having to re-load it every mouseover tick might be prohibitively expensive.

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve the same effect as I have shown below without re-initializing everything?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_datavisualization">
  <svg id="click" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
          <g id="pointer" transform="scale(0.5)">
              <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" id="dragcircle" />
          </g>
      </defs>
  </svg>
</div>



  <body style='overflow:hidden'>
  
    
    <script>
    
        // Get the viewport height and width
      const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
      const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0)
      
      // Fit to viewport
      var height            = vw*0.7;
      var width             = vw;
      
      // Create the canvas. We will use only part of it for the main plot
      var svg = d3.select("#click") // This selects the div
          .attr("width", width) // This defines the canvas' width
          .attr("height", height) // This defines the canvas' height
      
      
        
      
      // define the clipPath
      svg.append("clipPath")       // define a clip path
          .attr("id", "ellipse-clip") // give the clipPath an ID
        .append("ellipse")          // shape it as an ellipse
          .attr("cx", 175)         // position the x-centre
          .attr("cy", 100)         // position the y-centre
          .attr("rx", 100)         // set the x radius
          .attr("ry", 50);         // set the y radius

      // draw clipped path on the screen
      svg.append("rect")        // attach a rectangle
          .attr("id","cliprect")
          .attr("x", 125)        // position the left of the rectangle
          .attr("y", 75)         // position the top of the rectangle
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#ellipse-clip)") // clip the rectangle
          .style("fill", "lightgrey")   // fill the clipped path with grey
          .attr("height", 100)    // set the height
          .attr("width", 200);    // set the width
      
      
      // Shift the marker around on mouseover; restrict it to the contour
      var movex
      var movey

      svg
        .on("mousemove", function () {
        
            // Get the current mouseover coordinates
            movex = d3.event.x;
            movey = d3.event.y;

          // The only way I get this to work right now is by removing the previous clipped shape, then re-adding it
          d3.select("#cliprect").remove()
          d3.select("#ellipse-clip").remove()
          
          // define the clipPath
          svg.append("clipPath")       // define a clip path
              .attr("id", "ellipse-clip") // give the clipPath an ID
            .append("ellipse")          // shape it as an ellipse
              .attr("cx", movex)         // position the x-centre
              .attr("cy", movey)         // position the y-centre
              .attr("rx", 100)         // set the x radius
              .attr("ry", 50);         // set the y radius
            
          // draw clipped path on the screen
          svg.append("rect")        // attach a rectangle
              .attr("id","cliprect")
              .attr("x", 125)        // position the left of the rectangle
              .attr("y", 75)         // position the top of the rectangle
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#ellipse-clip)") // clip the rectangle
              .style("fill", "lightgrey")   // fill the clipped path with grey
              .attr("height", 100)    // set the height
              .attr("width", 200);    // set the width
          
          
            
          });

      
  
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in place of your mousemove callback

```
function() {
        
            // Get the current mouseover coordinates
            movex = d3.event.x;
            movey = d3.event.y;

  
          // move the clipPath
          d3.select("#ellipse-clip") // selects the clipPath
            .select("ellipse")          // selects the ellipse
              .attr("cx", movex)         // position the x-centre
              .attr("cy", movey)         // position the y-centre
            
          // move clipped path on the screen
          svg.select("rect")        // attach a rectangle
              .attr("x", movex)        // position the left of the rectangle
              .attr("y", movey)         // position the top of the rectangle

}
```